# Why my java code is not working which have some hashmap implementation

Tags: java, string, split, hashmap

**This is the code**

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = s.nextInt();
    int q = s.nextInt();
    HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        String extentions = s.nextLine();
        String arr[] = extentions.split(" ");
        map.put(arr[0], arr[1]);
    }
}
```

**For input consider this**

5 6

html text/html

htm text/html

png image/png

svg image/svg+xml

txt text/plain

index.html

this.file.has.lots.of.dots.txt

nodotsatall

virus.exe

dont.let.the.png.fool.you

case.matters.TXT

**You can see this coding question on code chef:**
https://www.codechef.com/problems/MIME2

**It is giving this Error: **
*case.matters.TXTException in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
at competitive._13.main(_13.java:21)*

Comment: Hint: What does this code return? `"nodotsatall".split(" ")`

Comment: Ya there is the problem.  Now solved

Answer (score 1):

You are splitting your strings on space (" ").

Some of your strings do not contain any spaces, for example

```
index.html
nodotsatall
```

So your arr[] will only contain 1 element. Therefore, when you try to access arr[1] you get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 1):

When you split user input with space (" ") or any other delimiter, make sure the user has entered valid input, if not discard that entry or take proper action (LOG) 
**Modified code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        int n = s.nextInt();
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            String extentions = s.nextLine();
            String[] arr = extentions.split(" ");
            if (arr.length == 2)
                map.put(arr[0], arr[1]);
            else
                System.out.println("Invalid input" + extentions);//Or log or any other action
        }
    }
}
```